# Angular 2, class attribute for customized component

Tags: javascript, angular

Is the class attribute useful in angular 2 for a customized component?
For example:

```
<app-my-first-component class='darkBackground'></app-my-first-component>
```

It looks like the class does not affect the component.

Comment: what are you trying to do which is not being reflected?

Comment: class attribute any where inside HTML is used to add a css class. Does your question makes sense?

Comment: I think he/she wants to pass the class attribute to child component. If that's the case, you can define global css style in the file `src/styles.css`. Otherwise, parent and child don't have same scope, so the css styles in parent are not accessible in child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address the class by adding a style to `app-my-first-component` like

```
@Component({
  ...,
 styles: [`
  :host(.darkBackground) {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgrey;
  }`]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use class attribute. And, there is another way to do the same, using host attribute.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-my-first-component',
host: {'class':'darkBackground'}
})
```